# windows product key

Tags: windows, oem, windows-7, license-key

I received from my distributer a wrong OEM version of a windows7, I dont have time to send it back and wait for an other.

Can I use the UK product key with a dutch dvd? (the one I used myself)

Comment: Which version of Windows 7 (Home, Pro, Ultimate)

I don't think it'll be a problem unless languages are involved in which case it might be a different but if you got the time, I would try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be np problem with Windows Phone Activation, as long as you use the product key that comes with your notebook (usually found on the bottom).